# Kakfa - string serialized as avro - how to deserialize?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have two apps - one of them produces messages to the topic and the other one reads from them. In the producer I set the `key-serializer` as:

```
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
```

But as a key in the message I sent string. Because of that in the zookeper a new schema was created which looks like this

```
"string"
```

And right now when I want to consume message in the kafka stream I don't know which serde should I use - a normal StringSerde or SpecificAvroSerde ?

When I use string serde I got some wrong keys, for example I get some additional numbers in the key that should be alphbetical only.

How to solve the issue without changing the serializer in the producer ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by you sent a string as a key in the message.  However I believe what has happened is data is being sent as confluent Avro binary.  And so a magic byte(s) is added in front of the serialized data to refer to the schema that was registered. (in addition to other formatting). You should try using the paired confluent Avro deserializer, it should remove the magic byte, look up the schema with it, and deserialize back into an Avro generic record.

Comment: From the Avro specification you can see that in addition to the magic byte(s) Confluent would add for the Schema Registry. the string in Avro format would be encoded with its length in front of it "a string is encoded as a long followed by that many bytes of UTF-8 encoded character data.
For example, the three-character string "foo" would be encoded as the long value 3 (encoded as hex 06) followed by the UTF-8 encoding of 'f', 'o', and 'o' (the hex bytes 66 6f 6f):
06 66 6f 6f"

Comment: When you use a string deserializer, it is trying to interpret that binary message (which includes the bytes for the string) as a string.  So you get Confluent Schema Registry byte(s), then the length, then the string likely, as you are reading serialized format of Avro binary.

Comment: Have you tried GenericAvroSerde?

Answer (score 1):

I will consolidate my comments.

I believe you are seeing numbers and then your string in your output, because your consuming application is considering Avro binary data as a string.  But serialization of data into Avro binary can add numbers in front (the length of the string for a string datatype)

http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#binary_encode_primitive (see string)

So I suspect your data was serialized to Confluent's variety of Avro binary, and these are the bytes you have in the key.  If your consuming application wants to deserialize the Avro binary format, you would then want a paired Confluent deserializer in your consuming application.  The result of the paired confluent Avro deserializer, is an Avro generic data record.  Your string will then be retrievable from the Avro generic data record programatically.

Note that the paired confluent deserializer will in some way need to have been passed your Schema Registry url, so that it could look up the schema to use to deserialize.  I am not sure how that is accomplished in your consuming applications infrastructure.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Yes exactly I thought the same - the only issue I have I don't know which serde. I tried to use `SpecificAvroSerde` but it cannot be of type java.lang.String. I just wonder how to generate the class from avro ?